# cakephp4 authentication login not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I am testing the cakephp 4 login authentication. I copied all the code from the cakephp4 tutorial authentication (see below for link) and  copied all code to my project as required and no errors were found.

i can create new logins but i cant actually login still.  My cakephp4 project is below (its just a test project using test data for the purpose of trying to get logins to work)

https://southernservices.com.au/crm4/users/login

```
This is the code where things get stuck

public function login()
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
   $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
    
 
    // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
    debug($result); //debug of output
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        // redirect to /articles after login success
        $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
            'controller' => 'Articles',
            'action' => 'index',
        ]);
        $this->Flash->success(__('Logged In!'));
        return $this->redirect($redirect);
    }
    // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
    if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
    }
   
}

in application.php here is the main function for authentication
  public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
{
    $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);

    // Load identifiers, ensure we check email and password fields
    $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password',
        ]
    ]);

    // Load the authenticators, you want session first
    $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    // Configure form data check to pick email and password
    $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password',
        ],
        'loginUrl' => '/users/login',
    ]);

    return $authenticationService;
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**debug output:**

> Login URL `https://southernservices.com.au/crm4/users/login` did not
> match `/users/login`.'

**Change:**

```
'/users/login',
```

**to:**

```
'/crm4/users/login'
```

**Or**

```
Router::url(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
```

**don't forget:**

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
```

Comment: ok it works but when i do a debug it throws an error like  debug($result); in login function?

Answer (score 0):

@Salines 's answer helped me to figure out what causes the problem.

The problem occurs when the site is not in the root folder, like in this example. In this case you have to set the base directory. In /config/app.php find the 'base' parameter of 'App' config. You will see something like this:

```
    'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
        'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
        'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
        'base' => false,
        'dir' => 'src',
        ...
```

In this example, change `'base' => false` to `'base' => '/crm4'`, then in /src/Application.php change all the occurrencies of `'/users/login'` with `Configure::read('App.base') . '/users/login'`.

The [Configuration section of the Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration) describes how to set the App.base config properly.